# Broadcom Wireless card pass-through into Ubuntu VM

Tags: drivers, wireless, virtualization, broadcom, qemu

I'm trying to set up my wireless card to be passed-through to a QEMU VM(just to check out device-passthrough and how it works). I'm able to use the wifi on my host machine just fine.

An lspci on the host shows the following info related to the card:
[image]

The kernel driver in use is "wl".

Now, I try to unbind the host driver and associate the vfio-pci driver with my wireless card as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash

# content of /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf is
# options vfio-pci ids=14e4:4331

# content of /etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf is
# options vfio_iommu_type1 allow_unsafe_interrupts=1

set -e

BDF="03:00.0"
GRP=12

echo "[+] loading vfio-pci"
sudo modprobe vfio-pci

echo "[+] Finding iommu group"
readlink /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:${BDF}/iommu_group

echo "[+] Devices in the group"
ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:${BDF}/iommu_group/devices

echo "[+] Unbinding device driver"
echo 0000:${BDF} | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:${BDF}/driver/unbind

echo "[+] Finding vendor, device ID"
lspci -n -s ${BDF}
val=$(lspci -n -s ${BDF} | cut -d' ' -f3)
vendor=$(echo $val|cut -d':' -f1)
deviceid=$(echo $val|cut -d':' -f2)
echo "-- vendor is ${vendor}"
echo "-- deviceid is ${deviceid}"

echo "[+] Binding to vfio-pci"
echo "${vendor} ${deviceid}" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

echo "[+] Checking /dev/vfio"
ls /dev/vfio

echo "[+] checking dmesg for vfio logs"
dmesg | grep -i vfio
```

At this point, doing an lspci shows that the device is associated with the vfio-pci driver.

[image]

Now, I boot up Ubuntu in QEMU with the device passed-through as the following arguments:

`-device vfio-pci,host=03:00.0,id=net0`

However, when checking "lspci -v" inside the VM, I see that the driver associated with the device is `bcma-pci-bridge`.

[image]

My doubts/questions are :

1. Am I passing the device to the VM in the right way? Based on the lspci output/dmesg output, this part seems to be correct.
2. Is "bcma-pci-bridge" being used the expected behavior? Is there any way to get the VM to use the "wl" driver with the device? Once I set this up, I'd like to poke-and-prod the "wl" driver, so it'd be useful to be able to set it up this way.

Comment: My understanding is that guest machines cannot use wireless adapters built in to the host, but rather must use USB wireless adapters.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with internal machines not picking up my card so I created a new virtual network in `virt-manager` with NAT set to forward to my wireless card. I then use `virtio` and just select that network in the VM settings.

[image: forwarding to wirelesscard]

edit - I don't know if you would be able to interact with the wireless card in the way you described using this method, so perhaps its not a canonical answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm passing devices to my VMs using exactly this method for a while and I never get any issue.

Using similar method to vfio bind you can forces a peripherial to bind to specific driver.

Procedure is as follow, unbind from current driver, modprobe `wl` then bind wifi card to it.

I cannot guarantee it will works, I guess `bcma-pci-bridge` is used due to iommu remapping, however when I bind my intel wifi to a VM, it uses the same driver as host.

Try this script inside your VM

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

BDF="00:04.0"

echo "[+] Unbinding old wifi device driver"
echo 0000:${BDF} | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:${BDF}/driver/unbind

echo "[+] Finding vendor, device ID"
lspci -n -s ${BDF}
val=$(lspci -n -s ${BDF} | cut -d' ' -f3)
vendor=$(echo $val|cut -d':' -f1)
deviceid=$(echo $val|cut -d':' -f2)
echo "-- vendor is ${vendor}"
echo "-- deviceid is ${deviceid}"
modprobe wl
echo "[+] Binding to wl driver"
echo "${vendor} ${deviceid}" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/wl/new_id
```